# Trim lines between two delimiters

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

Input file:

```
sip:+16309608112@216.221.154.227:5060;user=phone
sip:+17738959697;npdi@208.54.48.151:5060;user=phone
sip:7739469234@10.174.27.1;user=phone
```

How can I get the following output using `grep` or `sed`?

```
    +16309608112

    +17738959697;npdi

    7739469234
```

Comment: Sonal, did any of the answers solve your  problem? If so, please indicate which one by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using Awk:

```
awk -F'[:@]' '{print $2}' file
+16309608112
+17738959697;npdi
7739469234
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you're asking:

```
$ cat /tmp/your/input | sed -e 's/.*:\(\S\+\)@.*/\1/g'
+16309608112

+17738959697;npdi

7739469234
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cut` as well:

```
cut -d: -f2 file | cut -f1 -d@
# output
+16309608112
+17738959697;npdi
7739469234
```

Do you really need those blank lines in between?